# Why is blade directives used in Roles and permission? Explain me the example below here

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm given with a task of adding new features in a built-in application and I end up with a piece of code. I have no idea how its working.
On AppServiceProvider.php

```
 Blade::directive('hasRole', function ($expression) {
            $exp=explode(",",$expression);
            return "<?php if(Auth::user()->hasPermission($exp[0],$exp[1])): ?>";
        });
```

On blades:

```
@hasRole('travel_calendar','view')
        <button class="btn btn-space btn-default btn-big tactive" id="travel_menu_cal" ><i class="icon mdi mdi-calendar"></i> Calendar</button>
        @endHasRole
```

What does the view does in this code too.
Someone place explain me the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From top to bottom with inline comments:

```
// Declare a custom function with name 'hasRole' that can be used in Blade files
Blade::directive('hasRole', function ($expression) {
    // If there are comma's in the expression, split those and dump the resulting strings in an array
    $exp=explode(",",$expression);
    // Return some php code that evaluates to pseudocode:
        // if user has permission to expression
    return "<?php if(Auth::user()->hasPermission($exp[0],$exp[1])): ?>";
});

// Use defined function, expression exists of two string: travel_calendar and view
@hasRole('travel_calendar','view')
    <button class="btn btn-space btn-default btn-big tactive" id="travel_menu_cal" ><i class="icon mdi mdi-calendar"></i> Calendar</button>
@endHasRole
```

The whole thing basically evaluates to this:

```
If user has permission to view travel_calendar
    Then show button
```

Comment: ->hasPermission($exp[0],$exp[1])): what does this actually mean? ... Where should I define the view? ... If i change the name of the view .. User wont see the button ... please light me up a little now.. Thanks you so much

Comment: $exp[0] and $exp[1] are nothing more than the first two indices of the array you created with `explode`. In your example, `$exp[0]` is `'travel_calendar'` and `$exp[1]` is `'view'`

Comment: Thanks again for your insight

Comment: If it helped, please upvote and tick as an answer so the community can benefit!